# I am tryin to get json file from goodreads API but my code is not reading the file

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Its showing the following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import json

res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "gmaVsowZsITzZGWKQjQ3sQ", "isbn": "0743269268"})
data=res.json()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 'isbns' instead of 'isbn', there is no parameter called 'isbn' in the reviews file

Answer (score 0):

Your example return 422 'No ISBNs specified.'. Please fix it by renaming isbn to isbns

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'isbn' in params with 'isbns'

```
import requests
import json
res = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/book/review_counts.json", params={"key": "gmaVsowZsITzZGWKQjQ3sQ", "isbns": "0743269268"})
print(res.text)
data=res.json()
print(data)
```

Output

```
{"books":[{"id":16183,"isbn":"0743269268","isbn13":"9780743269261","ratings_count":41973,"reviews_count":76642,"text_reviews_count":1914,"work_ratings_count":45888,"work_reviews_count":83363,"work_text_reviews_count":2194,"average_rating":"3.70"}]}
{'books': [{'isbn13': '9780743269261', 'work_ratings_count': 45888, 'isbn': '0743269268', 'id': 16183, 'work_text_reviews_count': 2194, 'reviews_count': 76642, 'average_rating': '3.70', 'work_reviews_count': 83363, 'text_reviews_count': 1914, 'ratings_count': 41973}]}
```